# How do I find the peak frequency of a wav file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to python and signal processing and I was given a task to record audio for 'x' seconds and then find the peak frequency in the audio file.

So far I have successfully implemented the recording part (records as a .wav file, sample rate = 96kHz) but I am unable to correctly find and output the peak frequency in that file.

The goal of this task is that if a frequency above a certain threshold is found, other actions will take place. Could anyone please assist me on how to find the peak frequency.

So far I have attempted this using the scipy fft package and some pieces of code taken from research.

```
    from scipy import signal
    from scipy.io import wavfile
    from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft,fftfreq
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import wave 
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    import struct

    frate,data = wavfile.read('output.wav')
    print(frate)

    w = np.fft.fft(data)
    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(w))

    # Find the peak in the coefficients
    idx = np.argmax(np.abs(w))
    print(idx)
    freq = freqs[idx]
    freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * frate)

    print(freq_in_hertz)
    print("HZ")
```

When audio is recorded, the above code sometimes works but however, an incorrect peak frequency is detected (for example I record something that I know has frequencies of 10kHz but it says peak frequency detected is 6kHz)

Other times when I record audio and try to find the peak frequency, i get the following error message:
Exception has occurred: IndexError
index 547388 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 480000
  File "C:\Users\aviso\Documents\VS Code Projects\FinalDesign\HighFreqTest.py", line 22, in 
    freq = freqs[idx]